# The right way to create a rectangle hole with rounded corners on some surface?

Tags: modeling, topology

The right way to create a rectangle hole with rounded corners on some surface?

I have this one, but my example working pretty bad with subdiv mod.
[image]
[image]

---

Solution like this seems well, but without subdiv mod it haven't rounded corners. I want nice corners with and without subdiv.mod. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just avoid triangles and Ngons.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with subdivision, something like this is all you need:

[image]

As you can see, you can loosen or tighten the curve by bringing internal holding edges closer to, or further from, the corners, or dispensing with them altogether.